# import python pickle files into mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pickle

I have some pickle files, and I want to load them into Mongodb, without converting them into other formats like csv and JSON. Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: I've searched the pymongo and mongodb documentations and there is something called as mongo import using which we can import csv, json and BSON files into mongodb, but there is no direct way to import pickle files.

Comment: No way to do it. You have to serialize to BSON.

Answer (score -1):

```
collection.insert({'yourkey': Binary(yourPickleFiles))})
```